# Querying future dates when date is stored as a string

Tags: excel, vba, date

Date is stored as a string.

Date Example: 11012019

I need to query where dates are entered incorrectly as a future date, but I can't do that if it's being stored as a string.

Goal: Query future dates greater than today

Comment: The [`DateSerial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateserial-function) function might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets convert the string into date first. Then add a logic.

```
Dim strDate As String
Dim dteDate As Date

strDate = "11012019" 'This is the string date

strMonth = Left(strDate, 2) 'Get the month
strDay = Mid(strDate, 3, 2) 'Get the day
strYear = Right(strDate, 4) 'get the year

dteDate = DateSerial(strYear, strMonth, strDay) 'string converted to date


If Date < dteDate Then
MsgBox "Date is a future date."
Else
MsgBox "Date is either today or in the past."
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Very helpful! Now that I have this part done how do I convert all the strings into dates if I have a sheet that has a list of different dates that are all strings?

Comment: I am trying to think of a way to write if current row is less than todays date then delete current row and move onto next row. I want to see all future dates that may have been entered incorrectly.

Comment: I get what you mean. But my answer is gonna be too long for the comment section. Maybe ask again in another post and I'll answer if I see it.